# Posting a complex object with ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

How can I use `WebClient` object to send a POST request like this:

```
public static void SaveOrUpdateEntity(string url, object data)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

where its `data` is a `Person` object.

This is controller method

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody]Person person)
{
    VeranaWebService.SaveOrUpdatePerson(person);
}
```

and `Person` class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One way is to serialize it using newtonsoft json serialization routines.  Then on the API side, if the input is of type Person the binding engine reserializes it.

Comment: I would use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138242(v=vs.110).aspx) .. I personally find it easier to use. And yes, serialize your object using NewtonSoft.Json.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Newtonsoft.Json which will help you serialize your data to a json object. It can be used like this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void SaveOrUpdateEntity(string url, object data)
{    
    var dataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
        response = client.UploadString(new Uri(url), "POST", dataString);
    }
}
```

To learn more about the newtonsoft library, read [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm)